# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: DROP CONSTRAINT is only supported for Hibernate

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am trying to drop a foreign key constraint in a table but the SQL "DROP CONSTRAINT" Statement is not supported by ucanaccess. the error says:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: DROP CONSTRAINT is only supported for Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto "create"

Does anybody know a way around this?

```java
private void dropTables() throws SQLException {
        final String RENTALS = "RENTALS";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = metaData.getTables(null, null, RENTALS, null);

        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString(3).equals(RENTALS)) {
                statement.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE RENTALS DROP CONSTRAINT"  
                                                           + " custNumber;");
                statement.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE RENTALS DROP CONSTRAINT" 
                                                           + " vehNumber;");
                statement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS;");
                statement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE VEHICLE;");
                statement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE RENTALS;");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message implies that setting `hbm2ddl.auto` to `create` would solve the problem:

```
<entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create">
```

However, you might want to think twice before doing this, as this means that all the tables associated with your Hibernate entities will be created and dropped each time you start the application.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Tim. The creation and dropping of the tables are actually the behavior desired. But how do I add the entry key, Do I do it in my code or in my database(access)?

Comment: I don't know anything about your setup.  Try doing a global search in your project for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.  This should turn up the correct configuration file.